# Capturing groups, Many groups per line

Tags: c#, regex

I have some html with 'control sequences' in it, I have already removed the html tags from the content, now I'd like to turn the 'control sequences' into 'styles'.

After html tags are removed I have this...

```
"<!C43!><!TG!>Some Characters"
```

to ultimately produce this...

```
<span class="C43 TG">Some Characters</span>
```

and my faulty c# thus far :

```
Regex reg = new Regex("<!([^<>]+?)!>");

Match matches = reg.Match(line);
foreach (Group group in matches.Groups)
{
    // finds both groups,
    // and remove the control sequence
}
```

I've not got much in my 'foreach' yet, because it is incorrectly returning the following groups when I inspect it with a breakboint...

```
Group 1 : <!C43!>
Group 2 : C43
<it does not find second group :( >
```

Any help would be appreciated, but I'm mostly looking for the correct regular expression to find what I'm looking for in the string, but I'm also useless with the regular expression library, so most effective 'find group, store group, remove group from string i'm searching' would also be greatly appreciated as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the others said, you want to loop over `Match`es not over `Group`s as your pattern has only one group. The usual way to do this is either Michael Gunter's `for` loop or simply

```
Match m = reg.Match(line);
while(m.Success)
{
    // read class from m.Groups[1]
    m = m.NextMatch();
}
```

However, to solve your ultimate problem, getting out all the data separately and putting the string back together might be a bit annoying - especially if you want to do this replacement in multiple lines at once.

Therefore, you might want to look into [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy.aspx) (the version taking a callback). That way you can match everything in a single match, and then make use of .NET's unique capability to access multiple captures of a single group.

```
var line = "<!C43!><!TG!>Some Characters";

MatchEvaluator evaluator = new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceCallback);

string output = Regex.Replace(
    line,
    @"(?:<!([^<>]+)!>)+(.+)",
    evaluator
);
```

And somewhere else in your class:

```
static string ReplaceCallback(Match match)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder("<span class=\"");
    sb.Append(match.Groups[1].Captures[0].Value);
    for(int i = 1; i < match.Groups[1].Captures.Count; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(" ");
        sb.Append(match.Groups[1].Captures[i].Value);
    }
    sb.Append("\">");
    sb.Append(match.Groups[2].Value);
    sb.Append("</span>");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Setting up the string is probably easier with `String.Format` but I could not find a way at the moment to `String.Join` the `CaptureCollection`.

So what this is basically doing:

The pattern `@"(?:<!([^<>]+)!>)+(.+)"` matches one or more `<!...!>` "tokens" and then the rest of the line. While doing so it captures the contents of the `<!...!>`. At every repetition another capture is recorded and you can access them all later in the callback. After the `<!...!>` tokens we match and capture the rest of the line with `(.+)`. Note the `@` in front of the string: it makes the string verbatim, which you should always do when specifying regex patterns - otherwise you'll get problems when it comes to escaping. Also note that `?:` after the first opening parenthesis. This is to suppress capturing, because we don't need another capture that contains the delimiters `<!` and `!>` as well. Always using non-capturing groups unless you actually need capturing is also good practice.

The callback function then gets called for every match in the in the input. There is only one match that contains the entire line. That match has captured two tokens in group `1` and the rest of the line in group `2`.

So we can now simply build a string, that starts with `<span ="`, then a space-delimited list of all captures of group `1`, then `">`, then the captured rest of the line and finally the closing `</span>`.

As I said, if you find a way to `String.Join` the collection group, the callback function reduces to three lines or so.

If the distinction between `Match`, `Group` and `Capture` is still a bit fuzzy to you, I suggest setting a breakpoint in the callback function and just examining the `match` object there.

Comment: wow,perfect answer, your code worked like a treat! thank you! :-)

Answer (score 3):

You're looping on the wrong thing. Try this:

```
string line = ...;
Regex reg = ...;
for (var match = reg.Match(line); match.Success; match = match.NextMatch())
{
    // in here, don't bother with .Groups... you don't need it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your issue in RegexHero:

http://www.regexhero.net/tester

It captures the 2 groups as:

```
1: C43
1: TG
```

Are you sure your input is what you expect it to be? Are you iterating on the intended collection for the results?

Comment: oh... now your link is asking to install silverlight... i'll check it out

Comment: I'd say it has to do with your code. Debug the reg.Match response and inspect the properties, etc.